# Using Tufte's template for writing and selling a book

Tags: tufte

I wrote a book about a computer application and I would like to use the famous Tufte's template. But I really don't know if I have the right to use it for a commercial purpose. Does anybody know a little about that topic ?

Comment: What exactly is the _famous Tufte template_?

Comment: I think you want to mean `tufte-latex` class instead the _famous_ `Tufte's template`.

Comment: This looks like a legal question to me (as much about copying a design as any code): that would make it off-topic for us, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is on the Apache License version 2.0: https://www.ctan.org/license/apache2, so you have to examine that license carefully to decide if it fits your intended use. There is no easy answer to this question.